# How to prevent duplicated data in multiple Excel documents?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am running company stats in multiple Excel sheets, such as budget, expenses, personnel data, subsidy data, etc.

I have separated them in order to prevent having zillions sheets in 1 document. I also wanted to prevent having 100 months of data in 1 sheet. Having multiple documents for each task/group is very organized and it's pleasure to work on smaller files where each sheet represents 1 calendar month.

I started creating separated files for company stats after I spent years having everything in 1 file where I was lost maintain such document.

But now I have to copy the same data/results from one sheet to another. For example, if I calculate income and expenses for the previous month, I have to copy that to the budget document. Then I have to copy that data again into the sheet where I maintain salaries. Then copy it again to the sheet where I track taxes.

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Ideally, I would like to have all my data in 1 sheet to prevent coping from one file to another, but also I don't want to (again) end up having document with zillions rows of data and 100 sheets.

Could a solution be to have 1 document for each calendar month? It came to my mind now, but I have never tried such solution.

I am sure that dozens of you have been in the same problems like me and I would like to hear how you sorted your business papers.

Comment: Whoa! If you have some MS Access knowledge you could import all the sheets to a DATABASE, rather than manipulating sheets. Working with tables will cut your load after the initial manual build. Although you asked for an Excel solution, the best fit is database. Then queries are easy to get data on all data available. In database management you could set Primary Keys for nonduplicate data. If you're unfamiliar with Access DB and queries, it's worth the effort to invest time to learn. That's how I first started; feeling the limits of Excel. Creating forms on databases would be next.

Answer (score 0):

You can *link* data to/from other documents. Open both, copy from one, paste in the other with 'Paste Special/Links'.

This way, all documents for a month use the *same* base data.

Then, for the next month, copy the set of sheets and remove the month-specific data in them. The base data will still be available and linked.

I recommend making a plan (or graph) which data you want to keep in which documents before you start building the links (or chains of links), so you don't end up with a plate of spaghetti. Some data might be annual, some monthly; some might be valid forever.